# sugarcrm contacts dropdown and javascript

Tags: sugarcrm

I require something like this for my order creation.
I have the following fields in sugarcrm

```
name: text field
contacts :dropdown
etc ...
```

I need a dropdown of contacts with the fields from primary address from contacts populated here using javascript or ajax when I select a contact from the drop down in the order edit view.
It should populate all the fields from the contacts to the field listed .The contact fields are :

```
Primary Address
Street: 
City:   
State:  
Postal Code:    
Country:    

Other Address
Street: 
City:   
State:  
Postal Code:    
Country:    
Copy address from left:
```

It should populate to :

Shipping Address
Street: 
City:
State:
Postal Code:
Country:

Billing Address
Street: 
City:
State:
Postal Code:
Country:
Copy address from left:

Is it possible in sugarcrm.   What would be the code.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly complex, but I would make it using ajax. The following is only a suggestion, since there are several ways to implement such a change.

- Create /custom/moduels/Quotes/MyJS.js
- In MyJS.js make an ajax call which is executed when changing the contacts dropdown and that updates the shipping/billing info with the return values.
- Create /custom/modules/Quotes/MyFunctions.php
- In MyFunctions.php make the php function which is called by the ajax call. This function loads the contact's info and returns it in a JSON string
- Create a new entrypoint for the ajax call, which points to the MyFunctions.php
- Copy /modules/Quotes/tpl/Create/EditViewFooter.tpl to /custom/modules/Quotes/tpl/Create/EditViewFooter.tpl
- Edit EditViewFooter.tpl and make it include MyJS.js